# Distributing 10 euros among 5 people

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

In how many ways can you distribute 10 euros among 5 people by using 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50 cents and 1 and 2 euros (with an unlimited supply of every coin).

In part A of the question it doesnt matter what kind of coins you give the people.

At first I thought I could use the possible combinations of getting $a+b+c+d+e=10000$.

But this can only be used when $a , ... , e$ can have every value which is not the case.

Then I thought about using generating functions:
Since every person gets 2 euros the number of ways for every person to get the 2 euros should be the same I assume we are looking for the coefficient of $[x^{200}]$, and the generating function is:

$$g(x)=(x^0+x^1+x^2+...)(x^0+x^2+x^4+...)(x^0+x^5+...)(x^0+x^{10}+...)(x^0+x^{20}+...)(x^0+x^{50}+...)(x^0+x^{100}+...)(x^0+x^{200}+...)$$

To find the coefficient here we can rewrite this as:
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\frac{1}{1-x^{5}}\frac{1}{1-x^{10}}\frac{1}{1-x^{20}}\frac{1}{1-x^{50}}\frac{1}{1-x^{100}}\frac{1}{1-x^{200}}$$

For which we can make a combinatorial expression

$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^{k}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^{2k}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^{5k}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^{10k}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^{20k}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^{50k}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^{100k}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k}x^{200k} $$

But to find the coefficient of $x^{200}$ here wil take ages. Which makes me rethink my strategy. There must be some possible simplification somewhere. Does anyone have an idea here?? Maybe a variation on the first appoach?

For question B the choice of the coins does matter per person (for instance person A doesnt want any 1 cent coins). So for this problem I will have to use the generating function.. But still how..?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do the know the # ways to give 10 euros to a **single** person using the given denominations?

Comment: The dominant singularity of $g(x)$ is the pole of order $8$ at $x=1$, giving that the wanted coefficient is roughly $R\cdot\binom{207}{7}$ where $R$ is the residue at $z=1$.

Comment: @ChargeShivers the combinatorial expression of the generating function gives the # of ways to give 2 euros to one person. With the answer to that I can easily find the answer for 5 people

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks, will check out the maths behind dominant singularity of generating functions but we havent discussed this during the course so there must be another way to find the exact answer

Comment: If this is an routine exam question, then almost certainly you are not expected to use a giant generating function or count all the possible combinations of coins. The answer to part A is probably supposed to be $\binom{1004}4$ or $\binom{999}4$ and the method of solution to part B will depend on the precise conditions they give you.

Comment: You are right, the question in A is formulated a bit vaguely. "doesnt matter what coins you give to people" indeed suggested that we can consider only coins of 1 cent, which gives $\binom{1004}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little program.  Make an array ways with indices from $0$ to $1000$ and fill it with $1$s, representing that there is one way to give somebody any amount from $0$ to $1000$ cents using $1$ cent coins.  Then for each index $2$ and above in order let ways[i]=ways[i]+ways[i-2] which says you can either give them $i$ cents with $1$ and $2$ cent coins by giving them $i-2$ cents and adding a $2$ cent coin or by not using a $2$ cent coin.  Then starting at $5$ let ways[i]=ways[i]+ways[i-5].  Keep going for each type of coin.  You could do this in $1000$ lines and nine columns of a spreadsheet with copy down.  I get $321335886$ both ways.

Comment: Thanks Ross, this seems a good representation for the problem. The thing is that this is a problem from a combinatorics exam and they usually expect us to give the answer to these kind of questions in binomial coefficients. So i'm still looking for an answer by combinatorics.